# Using a callback function with custom hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have custom useDictation hook that hooks into a Speech-to-Text service. I want to append speech results every time a result is received.

The hook accepts a callback function that is fired when a final result is received from the service. It is called in a main component and fires every time a result is received. I want to show the sum of the results as they arrive.

I cannot access any useState methods or any other ways of updating the component's state. Everything stays static or does not update. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here?

```
function Component(){
  const [speechResults, setSpeechResults] = useState("")

  const callback = (results) => {
    setSpeechResults(prevState => prevState + results)
  }

  const [results] = useDictation(callback)

  return(
   //Shows the sum of all results returned
   <Text>{speechResult}</Text>
  )




}
```

For some reason, it will never add the sum of the results and will never encapsulate the state or current state. Is there a reason for this? Thank you!

Comment: "I want to show the sum of the results as they arrive." You know that you are concatenating strings, right?

Comment: Just return the data from useDictation and set the state in the component locally.

Comment: btw, I just noticed that you are also incorrectly assigning results as an array. This should be throwing an undefined error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const useDictation = async dataToProcess => await getDataFromRemoteApiService(dataToProcess);

const MyComponent = ({dataToProcess}) => {
    const [speechResults, setSpeechResults] = useState("");
    setSpeechResults(speechResults + useDictation(dataToProcess));
    return <Text>{speechResult}</Text>
}
```